# If-Else with few lines vs. Ternary Operator with more lines in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, if-statement, ternary, optimal

I have a Flutter program in which the click of a button changes something depending on the state of the button. I implemented it using ternary operator (which calls functions) and also with just an if-else block.

Using ternary:

```
 void functionA() {

 setState(() {
   //assignment op
   //assignment op
   //method call of a Dart class {
   //another setState }
   });
  }

 void functionB() {

  //method call of a Dart class
 }

 //in widget:

  ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            a = !a;
            a ? functionA(): functionB();
          }
        )`
```

Using if-else:

```
ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
           a = !a;
           if (a){

            //same sequence of operations as functionA()
           
            }else{
             
            //same sequence of operations as functionB()
            }
 
        )`
```

The code using the if-else statement is fewer lines versus the ternary operator that calls functions so which would be more optimal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They both work; it is just that the if-else is more readable than the ternary.

Comment: I also suggest that ternary not be used in a void context, since an if/else can only be used in a void context, and it keeps their domains relevant.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Thank you! Is one way faster than the other in this case?

Comment: in a void context, I suspect they compile to the same code!

Answer (score 0):

IF ELSE condition is more readable and clear.